# Center text vertically with whilst in the same line as float: right button

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with information, and a cancel `button` positioned to the right using `float`.

I want to center the information text vertically in the center, but whatever I try to use doesn't work.

How can I align the text so that it is vertically center, but keeping the same button height and cancel button position?

```css
.scb-frmo-frbtn {
  width: 75%;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c1) !important;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--dm);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  height: 57px;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > .title {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 18.5px;
  color: var(--c5);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > .desc {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > button.cancel-fr {
  float: right;
  background-color: var(--c6);
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--c6);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="scb-frmo-frbtn">
  <span class="title">username</span>
  <span class="desc">Outgoing Friend Request</span>
  <button class="cancel-fr">X</button>
</div>
```

What it looks like:
[image: output]

Comment: why dont you use flex property

Comment: Ravi Yadav, I already tried using that and align-self/align-content, but the button ended up not being positioned correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to center the text vertically by setting `line-height` to the height of the cancel (X) button.

As the button has a height of `40px`, I set the values to that.

```css
.scb-frmo-frbtn > .title {
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    line-height: 40px;
}
    
.scb-frmo-frbtn > .desc {
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```css
.scb-frmo-frbtn {
  width: 75%;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c1) !important;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--dm);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  height: 57px;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > .title {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 18.5px;
  color: var(--c5);
  line-height: 40px;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > .desc {
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.scb-frmo-frbtn > button.cancel-fr {
  float: right;
  background-color: var(--c6);
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--c6);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="scb-frmo-frbtn">
  <span class="title">username</span>
  <span class="desc">Outgoing Friend Request</span>
  <button class="cancel-fr">X</button>
</div>
```